# saving and retrieving from chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save a data object in chrome sync storage and then retrieve it, however the get() function always returns an empty object. The code I am using is,

```
function storeUserPrefs() {
  var key='myKey', testPrefs = {'val': 10};
  chrome.storage.sync.set({key: testPrefs}, function() {
    console.log('Saved', key, testPrefs);
  });
}

function getUserPrefs() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('myKey', function (obj) {
    console.log('myKey', obj);
  });
}
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but with `{key: "something"}` JS creates an object with a property named 'key', not the value of the key variable declared before. You can only use a variable on the right side of the colon. See section 'Creating a Direct Instance' [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The problem is with `chrome.storage.sync.set({key: testPrefs}`

Your data is stored as

```
{
    key: "{"val":10}"
}
```

So, your code `chrome.storage.sync.get('myKey')` return **undefined\empty object**.

## Solution I

Use string `"key"` as your key

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("key", function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

or

## Solution II

Set data through `"myKey"` Key.

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({"myKey": testPrefs})
```

**P.S** : Don't forget `chrome.storage.sync` is permanent storage API, Use [chrome.storage.sync.clear](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html#method-StorageArea-clear) before any further testing to see changes

## References

- [Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)

## EDIT 1

Use this code to set variable value in Chrome.storage

```
function storeUserPrefs() {
    var key = "myKey",
        testPrefs = JSON.stringify({
            'val': 10
        });
    var jsonfile = {};
    jsonfile[key] = testPrefs;
    chrome.storage.sync.set(jsonfile, function () {
        console.log('Saved', key, testPrefs);
    });

}
```

It generates following Output

```
Object{
    myKey: "{"val":10}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. So is there any way to use a string variable as a key in the set/get functions?

Comment: @source.rar:Check My **EDIT #1**, in the listed way it is possible, hope this helps :

Comment: None of these answers test for failure... quoting https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage: "Callback on success, or on failure (in which case runtime.lastError will be set)."

Answer (score 31):

A more fancy way to do it, and it handles errors as well:

```
const getStorageData = key =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, result =>
      chrome.runtime.lastError
        ? reject(Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message))
        : resolve(result)
    )
  )

const { data } = await getStorageData('data')


const setStorageData = data =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    chrome.storage.sync.set(data, () =>
      chrome.runtime.lastError
        ? reject(Error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message))
        : resolve()
    )
  )

await setStorageData({ data: [someData] })
```

Comment: wow, much better than the others solutions, and the error handling is great !

Answer (score 13):

```
function storeUserPrefs() {
    var key='myKey', testPrefs = {'val': 10};
    chrome.storage.sync.set({[key]: testPrefs}, function() {
      console.log('Saved', key, testPrefs);
    });
}
```

You could just force to evaluate the variable key using [key] when saving. That way is easy to set your keys dynamically.
Hope that helps.

Comment: how to use chrome.storage.sync.get ?

Comment: @swapnilgandhi something like that will help you read the value:

chrome.storage.sync.get("myKey", function(data) {
  console.log(Object.values(data)[0].val);
});

Answer (score 2):

As chrome.storage.sync can storage JS objects, you can just do this:

```
var save = {};
save["myKey"] = testPrefs;

chrome.storage.sync.set(save, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
testPrefs = JSON.stringify({
            'val': 10
        });
    var jsonfile = {};
    jsonfile[key] = testPrefs;
    chrome.storage.sync.set(jsonfile, function () {
        console.log('Saved', key, testPrefs)
```

Answer (score 0):

By using [WebExtension browser API](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) Polyfill you can use promises and also use TS and code like below for set sync of chrome and get sync

```
function getStore() {
    return chrome.storage.sync.get("myKey").then(function (value) {
        return value["myKey"];
    });
}

function setStore() {
    return chrome.storage.sync.set("myKey","value").then(function (value) {
        return "Success!";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as of then ECMA now got new syntac to simplify Your example

```
    function storeUserPrefs() {
    var key='myKey', testPrefs = {'val': 10};
        chrome.storage.sync.set({key: testPrefs}, function() {console.log('Saved', key, testPrefs);});
}

function getUserPrefs() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get('myKey', function ({myKey}) {
        console.log('myKey', obj);
    });
}
```

So now to get rid of object name You just need to destruct argument object and it will unwrap it.
Hennce look this syntax:

```
let ob={a:"me",b:"and" ,c:"myself",d:"and", e:"eye", f:"o_O"}

function someFunction( {c,d,f} ){
 console.log( c,d,f)  //output:   myself and o_O
}
```