# Chrome Extensions - Saving Settings

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first Chrome extension. It's a very simple thing I'm trying to do at this point so I can try and gain an understanding of how it works and build off of that.

Anyway what I am trying to do right now is I have a extension button that opens up a page with a TEXTAREA. I want the user to be able to enter text into this textarea box and save this to be called later (this setting also needs to be available to be called again the next time Chrome is opened, whatever they enter into this textbox I want to keep that value permanently unless they save over it).

My TEXTAREA id=test1

Here's my JavaScript

```
function saveSettings() {
    var storage = chrome.storage.sync;

    // Get signature value from text box
    var txtValue = test1.value;

    // Save using Chrome storage API
    storage.set(txtValue, function() {
        console.log("Saved");
    });
}

function insertText(text) {
      document.getElementById("test1").value= text;
}
```

For testing purposes I have a addEventListener for inserting a set text value to make sure the insert function works. I have a button for a hard coded set of text, then another button to try to insert the "saved" text which should be the var txtValue.

The insert function that WORKS

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var temp = document.getElementById('template');
    temp.addEventListener('click', function() {
        insertText('Hard Coded Text');
    message('Template Inserted');

    });
});
```

The insert function that does NOT work that is trying to insert the value typed into and saved into the TEXTAREA field.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('insert');
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
        insertText(txtValue);
    message('Saved Text Inserted');

    });
});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've looked at a bunch of different examples and most of them are similar to what I've done using storage.sync but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any code to retrieve the saved value?

Comment: In addition, `chrome.storage.sync.set` takes a JSON object, not a simple string value: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: The last set of code has an insertText(txtValue). The txtValue is supposed to be the saved value.

Comment: I have storage in the permissions in my JSON file. Should I be adding something else?

Comment: Sorry friend you're not really close to understanding the storage system right now - I'd suggest some more research. Have a look at this for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531102/saving-and-retrieving-from-chrome-storage-sync

Comment: Wow at a glance very confusing. Thanks for the link, after reading it over a couple times that sorta looks like what I'm trying to do. I'll have to do some more testing with that. Thanks for that link. Hopefully that gets me on the right track.

Comment: If you have more than 1-2 fields, I highly suggest using a lightweight option manager like [webext-options-sync](https://github.com/fregante/webext-options-sync). It'll saves you a lot of headaches

Answer (score 27, accepted):

to save

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ mytext: txtValue });
```

to get

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('mytext', function(data) {
    yourTextArea.value = data.mytext;
});
```

I found a new library to call chrome storage with Promise, pretty cool.

https://github.com/Selection-Translator/chrome-call

```
import { scope } from 'chrome-call'

const storage = scope('storage.local')
storage('get', 'flows').then(data => initFlows(data.flows))
```

More information: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/

Comment: Just to add: Using `chrome.storage` requires the `storage` permission in `manifest.json`: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: can i set all values like this?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan you can set all values

Comment: for reference:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/