# How do I save multiple dropdown menus in an application relaunch?

Tags: html, google-chrome-app

I have a program that has multiple dropdown menus and I am running it as a chrome unpacked extension but I cannot get any of the dropdown menus to save after I reopen the app. How can I achieve this? I have already attempted some  solutions but they have not worked. The dropdowns are in a table format.(Note: This is not all of my code but to make it more simple I only included two of my dropdowns). Thanks!

```html
<!--          <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
          <script src="java.js"></script>
                 
              </head>  -->
 
 <body>
      <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="images.jpeg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
  </div>
    <table id="t01">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>ID</th>  
    <th>In Use</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Connected to...
      *Based on OUTPUT*</th>
    <th>Comment</th>
  </tr>
<tr><td id="master01">1/4 Inch Audio Cables</td>
<td>1-2</td>
<td>--</td>
<td>2</td>
<td><select align="center" id="master01dropdown">
  <option value="option01">option01</option>
  <option value="option02">option02</option>
  <option value="option03">option03</option>
  <option value="option04">option04</option>
  <option value="option05">option05</option>
  <option value="option06">option06</option>
  <option value="Null">Null</option>
  <option value="Not Defined">Not Defined</option>
  <option value="Not in Use">Not in Use</option>
 </select></td>
<td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td align="center" id="cable01">6 feet</td>
<td>1</td>
<td><input align="center" checked type="checkbox" name="void" value="In use"><br></td>
<td>1</td>
<td><select id="cable01dropdown">
  <option value="option01">option01</option>
  <option value="option03">option02</option>
  <option value="option03">option03</option>
  <option value="option04">option04</option>
  <option value="option06">option05</option>
  <option value="option07">option06</option>
  <option value="Null">Null</option>
  <option value="Not Defined">Not Defined</option>
  <option value="Not in Use">Not in Use</option>
 </select></td>
<td></td>
I added the suggested code and it still will not work. *Note: I am not very good with JavaScript.*

    chrome.storage.sync.set({ items: 'master01,cable01,cable02'});
chrome.storage.sync.get('items', function(data) {
     var items = data.items.split(',');
     items[0] => (master01)
     items[1] => (cable01)
     items[2] => (cable02)
});
```

Comment: It seems that chrome has a storage where you can store this kind of "settings", you can save it in the store and get the value when you relaunch the app. If it has a value then you put that value in the dropdown, if it is empty then you put a default value. Take a look to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28277312/chrome-extensions-saving-settings

Answer (score 0):

Store items in chrome storage:

Suppose you save comma separated items

```
chrome.storage.sync.set({ items: 'item1,item2,item3,item4'});
```

fetch it using:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get('items', function(data) {
     var items = data.items.split(',');
     // items[0] => item1
     // items[1] => item2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll detail how to save and load an example options menu, containing a textbox and a checkbox. In your example, you'll want to use `document.getElementById('master01dropdown').value` in your save.

#### Setting up

First, create a file `options.html` in the root of the project, containing your form.

Next, make sure this options page is registered in your `manifest.json`:

```
"options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "chrome_style": true
}
```

At the bottom of your `options.html`, before `</body>`, include a JavaScript file:

```
<script src="js/options.js"></script>
```

Your form should also include a Save button somewhere with id `save`:

```
<button id="save">Save</button>
```

#### Saving

Inside your `/js/options.js` file, register the `save()` function to run when your save button is clicked:

```
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', save);
```

Your `save()` function should use Chrome Storage to save every element from your form. For example, to save a textbox and a tickbox:

```
function save() {
    var sitesToSave = document.getElementById('sites').value;
    var displayPopup = document.getElementById('popup').checked;
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        sites: sitesToSave,
        popup: displayPopup
    }, displaySavedMessage);
}
```

#### Loading

Inside your `/js/options.js` file again, register the `load()` function when your form is loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);
```

Now set those form fields from earlier with the saved values (and provide default values), again using Chrome Storage:

```
function load() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        sites: 'supersecretsite.com',
        popup: false
    }, function(items) {
        document.getElementById('sites').value = items.sites;
        document.getElementById('popup').checked = items.popup;
    });
}
```

Done! Settings can now be saved and loaded.

All code in this answer is from a very simple [example Chrome Extension](https://github.com/JakeSteam/SelectiveScrubber) I made, which also has an accompanying [detailed tutorial](https://blog.jakelee.co.uk/creating-a-history-clearing-chrome-extension/).

Comment: Thanks! I will make sure to try this sometime today and see if it works. I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: @Ahoop No worries! If you're still struggling, I recommend checking out the repo I linked, it has less than 10 files in it, and is very simple even without reading the blog post written about it.

Comment: Despite this being loaded as an unpacked extension (I should have specified this earlier) this is an app and I think the process of closing it is different than an extension so it is still defaulting back to the default value when I reopen the application

Comment: You should still be able to use Chrome local storage.. perhaps you need a different load trigger?

Comment: Would your recommend a specific load trigger?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure I'm afraid, I've never used Chrome apps. It's a shame my answer isn't useful to you! Btw, Chrome apps have been [discontinued for a couple of years](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), and I'm not sure anyone can use them...

Comment: Chromebooks are still able to use them but not Mac and PC. I am working on a chromebook so they are still accessible and it is nice to have an app like this that I never have to publish and is custom to what I want. (Haven't found a way to do this on Mac or PC yet).