# minifying javascript with quote_keys is not working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gulp, gulp-uglify

I'm minifying javascript using gulp.

My JS has objects like following

```
var a={"v":5}
```

But after minification it converts my object to following:

```
var a={v:5}// but I don't want it to remove quotes in keys
```

Because I'm using this javascript in chrome extension (basically I want to remove [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531102/saving-and-retrieving-from-chrome-storage-sync))

My gulp task is as following:

```
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('build1',function() {
    gulp.src(['../ext/app/background.js']).on('error', function(e){
        console.log("error:",e)
    }).pipe(uglify({mangle:true,quote_keys:true})).on('error', function(e){
        console.log("error1:",e)
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('../ext/app'));
});
```

Comment: It's no difference between `{v: 5}` and `{"v": 5}`. Because in first case `v` will be string also. The error by link isnt related to your case. It is about `a[key]` vs `a["key"]` case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are passing the `quote_keys` as an option instead of enclosing it in `output` option in the gulpfile while using the `gulp-uglify` package. Try this and you will get the desired output.

```
 gulp.task('build1',function() {
    gulp.src(['a.js']).on('error', function(e){
        console.log("error:",e)
    }).pipe(uglify({output:{quote_keys:true}})).on('error', function(e){
        console.log("error1:",e)
    }).pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
   });
```